# Website that describes MySQL installation on Windows

Tags: php, mysql, installation

Some time back i had installed MySQL on Windows. Firstly,I got to learn that MySQL doesn't has any IDE of it own, some other tools are needed for that. Is that true?

Secondly & most importantly, installation had failed on my windows PC. Hence i need a website that could provider me installation WITH pictures of installation. I had got one, but installation had failed. don't remember what error was!

Plus, if MySQL needs an IDE, can you recommend one for me!

Thanks!

Comment: Running the installer is not hard. Why do you need screenshots for that?!

Comment: @Thief: To make sure that installation that i do doesn't break or threw any error

Comment: You forgot the error message? Try again, then come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an installation guide with screenshots, for version 5.0 but still should be generally the same process:

http://www.netikus.net/documents/MySQL-Server-Installation.pdf

As far as an IDE, if you mean a GUI tool to use for making changes to the database structure (DDL) and for working with data (DML), try Toad for MySQL:

http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/

Answer (score 3):

I think You should use Wamp or Xamp as both server gives Php and Mysql in built.After installing you can easily use MySQL.Anyway check these links that might help you.

```
http://www.netikus.net/documents/MySQL-Server-Installation.pdf
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-the-MySQL-Database-Server-on-Your-Windows-PC
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to search for "WAMP" since most people want Apache and PHP as well as MySQL.  There are lots of sites that will help you install WAMP.

MySQL doesn't really need an IDE - you will want to look for a host language IDE (for PHP or whatever host language you wish to use).

Good luck!